# Powershell Export to .csv file error

Tags: powershell, ssms, powershell-2.0

```
PS SQLSERVER:\sqlregistration> Get-ChildItem 'SQLSERVER:\SQLREGISTRATION' -Recurse | export-csv reorder.csv
Export-Csv : Cannot open file because the current provider (SqlServer) cannot open a file
.
At line:1 char:65
+ Get-ChildItem 'SQLSERVER:\SQLREGISTRATION' -Recurse | export-csv <<<<  reorder.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Export-Csv], PSInvalidOperationExcep
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ReadWriteFileNotFileSystemProvider,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co
   mmands.ExportCsvCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the sqlserver provider which won't let you create files.   call

```
Get-ChildItem 'SQLSERVER:\SQLREGISTRATION' -Recurse | export-csv C:\reorder.csv
```